# Surjectivity of composition

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I know that this question has been posted few times, but I want to check MY proof, because this is my first time trying to prove anything in mathematics. (I'm afraid if I just copy paste their proofs I won't learn anything.)

Let $S_1,\space S_2, \space S_3$ be sets and $f $ and $g$ functions that are defined as:

$f:S_1\mapsto S_2\\g:S_2\mapsto S_3$

Functions $f$ and $g$ are surjective:

$$\forall y\in S_2\exists x\in S_1:f(x)=y\\\forall z\in S_3\exists y\in S_2:g(y)=z$$

We want to prove:$$\forall z\in S_3\exists x\in S_1:(g\circ f)(x)=z.$$
Let $z\in S_3$, then for each $z$ there is a particular $y\in S_2$ by the function $g$, $g(y)=z$. Also let $y\in S_2$, for each (particular) $y$ there is a particular $x\in S_1$ by the function $f$, $f(x)=y$.  This implies that $z=g(y)=g(f(x))=g\circ f(x).$ This proves the statement.

/Also another way would be to substitute particular $x$ with for example $x_1$, and same goes with $y$, then plug it into the formula, and say that this is true for all $z$./

Sub-question: could I write it in a logical way like this:$$((y\Rightarrow x)\wedge(z\Rightarrow y))\Rightarrow(z\Rightarrow x)\equiv\\\equiv((z\Rightarrow y)\wedge(y\Rightarrow x))\Rightarrow(z\Rightarrow x)$$

Comment: About the sub-question, you have to avoid using $⇒$ with two meanings; you have used it both as logical *connective* ("if___, then ...") and as shorthand for "maps" (from $y$ to $x$).

Comment: Yes, you should use \mapsto to represent function mappings and \implies for implications.

Comment: Didn't know how to write it, thanks. @Mauro, I noticed it 1 (or more) min(s) ago, I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording of your proof seems a bit off to me.  Think about what we want to show.  Surjectivity of $g \circ f$ means that, given any $z \in S_3$, we can find an $x \in S_1$ such that $g \circ f(x)=z$.  So here is one way to do it:

Suppose $z\in S_3$.  Since $g$ is surjective, there exists $y \in S_2$ such that $g(y)=z$.  Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $x \in S_1$ such that $f(x)=y$.  Then $g \circ f(x)=g(y)=z$.

Note that in this proof, both $x$ and $y$ were chosen after $z$ was fixed, and they depend on $z$.

Comment: I thought I wrote the same thing just a bit detailed (because I defined surjectivity of each function again through text)?